# Embedded django site seems to have a problem with its CSP settings

Tags: django, google-app-engine, csrf, app.yaml

My django(2.1) app needs to be able to be embedded in an iframe in a partner's website. I'm currently running it on google app engine where I have the following app.yaml settings:

```
handlers:
    - url: /.*
      static_dir: static/
      secure: always
      http_headers:
        Content-Security-Policy: "frame-ancestors 'self' partnersite .com *.partnersite.com www.partnersite.com;"
```

I can now access the login page through the partner site but when I try to log in I get the following error:

```
CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.
Reason given for failure:

    CSRF cookie not set.
```

The templates have {% csrf_token %} tags. I'm stumped, if anyone has any help or feedback please let me know.

Comment: Looks like you should enable CORS too.

Comment: Have you tried [exempting the view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/csrf/#csrf-protection-should-be-disabled-for-just-a-few-views) that serves the response?